# How can I choose which field to return in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

With the driver Java Mongodb, I am looking for a way to return just rsome fields. For example, I have a collection "users" with fields : "id", "Displayname", "AboutMe",... and I just want to return "id" and "AboutMe"

Answer (score 0):

you can try this sampled

```
 collection.find(eq("id", "123"))
    .projection(include("id", "AboutMe"));
```

here is link to basic query in java mongodb
[Mongodb Documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Comment: i've tried it before , but it doesn't work for me , one error appears in projection function  , (can not find symbole projection)  knowing that i use  java-mongodriver 3.0.2